# PayPal Intent Time Limits

Tags: php, paypal

I'm using the Paypal Rest API in PHP

I'm building a payment process system on my site but I wanted to know the limits (in time) I have on each time of payment capture.

How long do I have till I have to capture / complete the payment in the following situations:

1. Intent is Sale (Using Create), Method is Paypal
2. Intent is Authorize, Method is Paypal
3. Intent is Sale, Method is Credit Card
4. Intent is Authorize, Method is Credit Card

If this is a repeat question please let me know, I've search but unable to find an answer, if there is one, please let me know.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Immediately after calling `/execute`. `/execute` must be called within 3 hours of the original `/payment` call.
2. You can capture up to 29 days after the authorization was granted, though funds are only guaranteed for the first three working days.
3. Immediately. No `/execute` call needed as that's needed for a PayPal payment only.
4. You can capture up to 29 days after the authorization was granted, though funds are only guaranteed for the first three working days.

Hope this clears it up!

Comment: would you know if there is a way for me to process a payment three months after they have authorized it without saving there credit card information in the vault. I want people to preorder in advance, but I know Paypal does not actually check the credit card data that is stored in the vault till you charge it.